# Why is the do while loop exiting in this scenario when i enter 'y' as input character?

Tags: c, loops, do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c = 'y', temp;
    printf("Press y\n");
    do {
        printf("Press y to continue\n"); // read y again and again
        scanf("%c", &c); // y entered
        printf("%c", c); // loop should repeat but doesn't repeat
    } while(c == 'y');
}
```

Comment: Did you account for the fact that `stdin` is line buffered and the newline character will be rejected in the next iteration?

Comment: This is guaranteed to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not. Because `scanf` reads the `\n` character on second iteration which cause the loop to terminate. Place a space before `%c`to consume this `\n` character left behind by previous `scanf`.

```
 scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a space before `%c` which is a scanf quirk. The space absorbs the newline char after typing the 'y'.

```
        scanf(" %c",&c);
```